# export to pdf Promise unhandled

Tags: react-native, export-to-pdf

I am building an iOS app with React native and I want to have a button which when clicked it will export some text data into a pdf file.
The problem is that I use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib) and I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZEkQ.png).

My code is the following:

```
    exportPDF = async () => {

      const page1 = PDFPage
        .create()
        .setMediaBox(200, 200)
        .drawText('You can add text and rectangles to the PDF!', {
          x: 5,
          y: 235,
          color: '#007386',
        })
        .drawRectangle({
          x: 25,
          y: 25,
          width: 150,
          height: 150,
          color: '#FF99CC',
        })
        .drawRectangle({
          x: 75,
          y: 75,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          color: '#99FFCC',
        });

      const page2 = PDFPage
        .create()
        .setMediaBox(250, 250)
        .drawText('You can add JPG images too!')


      // Create a new PDF in your app's private Documents directory
      const docsDir = await PDFLib.getDocumentsDirectory();
      const pdfPath = `${docsDir}/sample.pdf`;
      PDFDocument
        .create(pdfPath)
        .addPages(page1, page2)
        .write() // Returns a promise that resolves with the PDF's path
        .then(path => {
          console.log('PDF created at: ' + path);
          // Do stuff with your shiny new PDF!
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));

  }
```

Does anybody know how to fix the unhandled promise rejection?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your piece of code, however: 1) can you update your code question adding your `PDFLib` import statement? 2) did you `link` the library after adding it as a dependency?

Comment: I have linked the library without error warnings but It does not work. I think that I have to manually link the library on Xcode something that I do not know how to.

Comment: There is a [manual installation](https://github.com/Hopding/react-native-pdf-lib#manual-installation) section in the library readme. If the problem persists it might be the case to open an issue on GitHub.